# Why nest Scala Option within itself?

Tags: scala

I just saw someone desire to use the following construction:

```
val x: Option[Option[Int]] = Some(None)
```

Can someone provide an example of where this would be useful?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can put this in the context of Scala `Map[String, Int]`.

```
Map("a" -> Option(1), "b" -> None)
```

`m.get(key)` has three possible output types.

If the key exists, and has a value, we get `Some(Some(1))`.

```
scala> m.get("a")
res28: Option[Option[Int]] = Some(Some(1))
```

If the key exists, but does not have a value, we get `Some(None)`.

```
scala> m.get("b")
res29: Option[Option[Int]] = Some(None)
```

If if the key does not exist at all, we get `None`.

```
scala> m.get("c")
res30: Option[Option[Int]] = None
```

This is useful in cases where you need to encode three states:

- exists with value
- exists without value
- does not exist

Most of the time we (I) don't care about the second condition, so we collapse to `Option[Int]`, but it is still certainly useful.

Comment: The REPL output kind of sealed it, the rest of the output very helpful as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Example: a function that opens a file, and read an `Int` from it.

- If there's no file, you'll get a `None`
- If there's a file but no integer inside of it, you'll get a `Some(None)`
- If there's a file but which contains an `123`, you'll get a `Some(Some(123))`

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the answer!